# How to use augment with a model on new data

Tags: r, dplyr, broom

It is fairly straightforward to use the `augment` function from the Broom package in R to add predictions back into a tibble. Viz.

```
df <- iris %>%
  nest(data = everything()) %>%
  mutate(model = map(data, function(x) lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, data = x)),
         pred = map2(model, data, ~augment(.x, newdata = .y))) %>%
  unnest(pred)
```

However, when I take a linear model trained on one set of data and try and predict on new data I receive the following error.

```
mod <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, data = iris)

df2 <- iris %>%
  mutate(Sepal.Width = Sepal.Width + rnorm(1)) %>%
  nest(data = everything()) %>%
  mutate(pred = map2(mod, data, ~augment(.x, newdata = .y)))

# Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `pred`.
# x No augment method for objects of class numeric
# i Input `pred` is `map2(mod, data, ~augment(.x, newdata = .y))`.
```

How should I use `augment` to fit new data? Is using an external model object (in the example above this is `mod`) the best practice or is there a more elegant way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having just posted the question, I think I have an answer. I won't accept the answer for 48 hours just in case someone contradicts or provides a more comprehensive one.

In the example, `map2` expects `mod` as a vector or list but it is a model object. Putting `mod` into the tibble as a list object suppresses the error and correctly calculates predictions.

```
mod <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, data = iris)

df2 <- iris %>%
  mutate(Sepal.Width = Sepal.Width + rnorm(1)) %>%
  nest(data = everything()) %>%
  mutate(mod = list(mod)) %>% #! this is the additional step
  mutate(pred = map2(mod, data, ~augment(.x, newdata = .y))) %>%
  unnest(pred)
```

Alternatively, coerce the external model object as list.

```
...
  mutate(pred = map2(list(mod), data, ~augment(.x, newdata = .y))) %>%
...
```

Comment: FWIW it looks like map2 **can** see external objects. The issue is it expects vector or list objects rather than raw models. Amending the line to read `mutate(pred = map2(list(mod), data, ~augment(.x, newdata = .y)))` works.

Answer (score 1):

Since there is only one model we can do this without using `map`.

```
library(dplyr)

df1 <- iris %>%
  mutate(Sepal.Width = Sepal.Width + rnorm(1)) %>%
  tidyr::nest(data = everything()) %>%
  summarise(pred = broom::augment(mod, newdata = data[[1]]), 
            mod = list(mod), 
            data = data)
```

Comment: That is a neat trick. I don't think it will scale well with multiple models, which is where I want to go with this approach. The column names are modified with a `pred.` prefix, which is a positive or negative feature depending on what you're after.